# ld: library not found for -lIOKit

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios6, iokit

I have added libIOKit.dylib to my project to get imei number and after that it started giving me the below linker error.

```
ld: library not found for -lIOKit
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

How can I solve this?

I have set "`Build Active Architecture Only`" to `yes` and also removed `armv7s` from `valid architectures`, even though it is still the same.

[image]